# UserControl Dropdown items clearing on selecting new value in ASP.net VB

Tags: asp.net, dropdown

After selecting a new value in the dropdown the items are becoming empty on postback. 
    Page Load of UserControl
    {
     If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
     Populate_MonthList()
     Populate_YearList()
    End If
    }

index change of dropdown

```
Sub Set_Calendar(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)
    'Whenever month or year selection changes display the calendar for that 
     month/year        
    calendar1.TodaysDate = CDate(drpCalMonth.SelectedItem.Text & " 1, " & 
         drpCalYear.SelectedItem.Value)
    If (Sender.Id = "drpCalYear") Then
        Populate_YearList(True)
    End If
    'whenever month or year changes 

End Sub
```

Can some help what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your events that fill the dropdownlist within  `If Not IsPostBack = True Then` or else your dropdownlist will be re-created, thus losing your selected value. As long as your events are within the `isPostBack` you should be able to access your selection.